Service worker race condition between message listener and fetch listener
My service worker has a variable to store a secured hash, and injects it into headers for relevant HTTP requests, server app will then compare with its own to make it a secured login.
The hash is generated dynamically behind (in browser class using c# dotnet in my case).
Previously I always called postmessage on page loaded from browser to update the hash into sw. But encountered an issue that with 5-6 min inactive (without opening devtools), once click the button on page, sw is re-initialised or wake up with empty hash value, thus responding with empty value and failed the validation.
So I added a trigger from sw, but then encountered the race condition between message listener and fetch listener. I need the message listener to update the hash in sw, but fetch listener reposonded at same time. Seems timeout delay is not working.
console.log('top root log');

if (!self.secureHeader) {
    self.secureHeader = 'Empty';
    console.log('Refreshing header');

    // this is my trigger when sw re-init
    postMessage({ type: 'refreshHeader', msg: '' }, '*');

    //// this is a bad attempt which didn't block the listener
    // setTimeout(function() {
    //     console.log('timeout ended');
    // }, 50);
}
self.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    if (event.data.type == 'setHeader') {
        self.secureHeader = event.data.msg;
        console.log('Header received:'+ self.secureHeader);
    } 
}, false);

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
    console.log(Responding: ${self.secureHeader});

    ////I tried timeout here, error: The event handler is already finished.
    //if (self.secureHeader === 'Empty')
    //timeout to do respond

    e.respondWith(
        fetch(request, {
        headers: getSecureHeaders(request)
    })
    .catch(() => {
        return caches.match(request);
    })
    );
});

From my testing, after a few minutes waiting and sw expiry,
The logs appear to be:
(sw wake up) top root logs appear.
"Refreshing header" triggered.
fetch event started.
Then "Header received" and "Responding..." comes at the same time,
how can I properly chain them? Any advice, thanks.

Try placing fetch() in the "message" event handler.

Are you trying to re-implement cookies?

You'll have to wake-up your worker from the main document, or use an interval in the worker (not great but work over many hours). Going next, there is a Web API for that, that works only on Webkit, by now: The Web Periodic Background Synchronization API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Periodic_Background_Synchronization_API

Workout with a lazy way and another elegant way using Promise.
1. Add a delay inside respondWith
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (e) {
    function delayPromise(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    e.respondWith(
        new Promise(resolve => {
            if (self.secureHeader === 'Empty') {
                delayPromise(50)
                    .then(() => {
                        resolve(handleFetch(e));
                    });
            }
        })
    );
});

2. chain promises to respond
self.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    if (event.data.type == 'setHeader') {
        self.secureHeader = event.data.msg;
        if (self.resolveHeader) {
            self.resolveHeader();
            self.resolveHeader = null;
        }
    } 
}, false);


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
e.respondWith(
        new Promise(resolve => {
            if (self.secureHeader === 'Empty') {
                self.headerPromise = new Promise((headerResolve, headerReject) => {
                    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                        headerReject(new Error('timed out'));
                    }, 200);

                    self.resolveHeader = () => {
                        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                        headerResolve();
                    };
                });

                self.headerPromise
                    .then(() => resolve(handleFetch(e)))
                    .catch((error) => {
                    });

            } else {
                resolve(handleFetch(e));
            }
        })
    );
});



Creating a timeout won't stop the fetch event handler. You need a promise that you can wait for before making the fetch() request. You can initialise that promise when asking for the refreshed header:
// runs when sw (re-)init
self.secureHeaderPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('Refreshing header');

    postMessage({ type: 'refreshHeader', msg: '' }, '*');

    self.setSecureHeader = (value) => {
        console.log('First header received: '+value);
        resolve(value);
 
        // allow later updates
        self.setSecureHeader = (value) => {
            console.log('Header received :'+value);
            self.secureHeaderPromise = Promise.resolve(value);
        };
    };
});
self.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    if (event.data.type == 'setHeader') {
        self.setSecureHeader(event.data.msg);
    } 
}, false);

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
    console.log(`Got request: ${e}`);
    e.respondWith(
        self.secureHeaderPromise.then(secureHeader => {
            console.log(`Forwarding request: ${secureHeader}`);
            return fetch(request, {
                headers: getSecureHeaders(request)
            })
        }).catch(() => {
            return caches.match(request);
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('Responding');
            return response;
        })
    );
});

